# Timeout Error - Sending mail through SQL Mail - Service Broker Queue

Tags: sql, timeout, service-broker

This is my first question! So I hope I provide enough information:

We are attempting to send around 1000 emails by taking advantage of the SQL Mail Service Broker. We are relatively new to this, but have hit a wall with this problem:

**Some Background:**

We created a Profile, an Account and a ProfileAccount entries, and enable database mail. We then tested with a few emails and all worked fine. We then created a store procedure that we would call from our project to QUEUE all the emails using msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail. This worked well, and we can see all the mail queued up successfully in msdb.dbo.sysmail_mailitems. The Service Broker then fires into action and starts processing the emails.

**The Problem:**

After sending roughly 90 or so (never the same number) an error is reported many times in the sql event logs

> The mail could not be sent to the recipients because of the mail
>   server failure.(Sending Mail using Account 42 (2011-09-19T17:20:09).
>   Exception Message: Cannot send mails to mail server. (The operation
>   has timed out.). Sending Mail using Account 42 (2011-09-19T17:21:59).
>   Exception Message: Cannot send mails to mail server. (Failure sending
>   mail.). )

I refered to this website for help:
http://www.sqlteam.com/article/how-to-troubleshoot-service-broker-problems

Which made me a little confused, I have run Query Profiler while the Broker is running and all seems fine.

I executed this:

```
    select * from sys.dm_broker_queue_monitors
```

which displayed the broker queue with a state of NOTIFIED.
This 'NOTIFIED' state seem to imply that the activation sp wasn't working, but the logs don't indicate this, and I checked all the following which didn't give me any clue:

```
    select * from sys.transmission_queue;
    select * from sys.conversation_endpoints;
    select * from sys.dm_broker_activated_tasks;
    select * from sys.dm_broker_connections;
```

If I run the following commands:

```
    EXEC msdb.dbo.sysmail_stop_sp;
    EXEC msdb.dbo.sysmail_start_sp;
```

the broker starts up again, and the same thing happens.

The windows event log seemed to show the most helpful message, but I'm unsure how to solve it:

```
    Event Type: Error
    Event Source:   DatabaseMail
    Event Category: None
    Event ID:   0
    Date:       9/19/2011
    Time:       5:18:44 PM
    User:       N/A
    Computer:   _____
    Description:
    There was an error on the connection. Reason: Timeout expired.  The timeout period elapsed prior to obtaining a connection from the pool.  This may have occurred because all pooled connections were in use and max pool size was reached.
    Timeout expired.  The timeout period elapsed prior to obtaining a connection from the pool.  This may have occurred because all pooled connections were in use and max pool size was reached.
```

And together with that the if I run this: "select * from dbo.sysmail_log;" I see long list of the timeout errors I showed at the top of this post. I have also discovered that when all these errors occur it closes down the Broker Service (Message Poisoning I think it's called) so therefore I need to run the sysmail_stop_sp and start to get it going again.

Thanks for your help, and I hope I provided enough information.

Charles

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have had a similar problem, but unfortunately never got an answer. In the end, all that I could do was to monitor the QUEUE and when it has crashed just restart it. I used the following stored procedure to do this.

```
DECLARE @state nvarchar(50),
        @length int,
        @last_activated_time datetime
CREATE TABLE #MailStatusTempTable
(
[queue_type] nvarchar(max),
[length] int,
[state] nvarchar(max),
[last_empty_rowset_time] datetime,
[last_activated_time] datetime
)
INSERT INTO #MailStatusTempTable EXEC msdb.dbo.sysmail_help_queue_sp @queue_type = 'mail'
SELECT TOP 1 @state = [State],@length=[length],@last_activated_time = [last_activated_time] FROM #MailStatusTempTable
DROP TABLE #MailStatusTempTable
IF (@length>0)
BEGIN
    IF (@state <> 'RECEIVES_OCCURRING')
    BEGIN
        IF (DATEDIFF(minute,@last_activated_time,GETDATE())>5) --ensuring 5 minutes has passed since last activity (your timeout might be different)
        BEGIN
            EXEC msdb.dbo.sysmail_stop_sp
            EXEC msdb.dbo.sysmail_start_sp
        END
    END
END
```

I hope this is of some help to you. If so, please remember to mark this as the answer!

Kind regards, 
Willem