# Time out error in Database mail

Tags: sql-server, database-mail

I'm taking database backup every day, with job of course. But now I want to send that backup file to another place and want to use for that Database mail.

I configured Database mail and can send files with size less than 10 MB (at least I tested up to this size) without any problem. But my database backup size is approx 350 MB and when I'm trying to send it I'm getting error

> Exception message: Cannot send mails to mail server(The operation has
>   timed out)

. How can I fix this problem, has anyone encountered with the same problem?

Comment: Probably this can help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7474685/timeout-error-sending-mail-through-sql-mail-service-broker-queue

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I increase the maximum allowed attachment size for email sent using msdb.dbo.sp\_send\_dbmail in Microsoft SQL Server 2005/2008](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/997628/how-do-i-increase-the-maximum-allowed-attachment-size-for-email-sent-using-msdb)

Answer (score 0):

If on SQL Server 2008 the following KB should help resolving this issue: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/968834